# How to sing like a crooner?

Tags: voice, voice-training

I'm taking singing lessons since last September and I've found that my voice is more developed now that how it was before. I've been trying to make my voice more clear and making my color more uniform within my vocal range (I'm a baritone / high baritone).

I've been practising some Frank Sinatra and Michael Buble songs, and I was hoping to get some advices on how to sing like a crooner. It's difficult to keep this "crooner" color in all phrases and sometimes my voice goes too much to chest resonance and then too little.

Any advice on where to feel the resonance or in general? Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to share a tip that helped me achieve this sound. Probably it's going to be different in each voice, but at least you can try and see if it helps. A little smile while singing in the baritone mid / low range helps getting the sound more clear and uniform. The vowels come out of your mouth in a different way with this smile (they're kind of weird at the beginning) so you have to practise a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already taking singing lessons then I would suggest the best person to ask is your singing teacher. She has a distinct advantage over someone on the internet in that she's actually heard your voice (and also has years of training and experience teaching).

It sounds like you have a clear idea of the sound you want to achieve and a pretty clear idea of how you feel you're falling short. Tell her this is an area you want to work on and she should be able to help you.

Voices are very individual things; what works for one person doesn't always work for another, and the individual advice a good teacher can give you is invaluable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I'm already doing that. I was just asking if anyone had any advice, because although you say that what works for one person doesn't always work for another, I want to know what people experience and learn how people learn to do it. That helps you understand your voice in a better way.